# How to constantly update data to a page using Node.js and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hogan.js

I'm new to Node.js and Express and working on an application that pings websites and displays the results on a page. Also using HoganJS / templating too. I'm trying to figure the process to get this working.

I have a block of code that runs every set interval and returns a JSON object. I want to render that onto an HTML page and update every time it runs. I know that Express uses the `res.render` but how would I get it to keep updating / rendering and in real time?

Comment: I think, you should take a look at socket.io to continuous data updates.

Comment: I've looked into `socket.io`. Some of the concerns I have is that the Express module for it `express.io` appears to only work with version 4 of the framework.

Comment: @MathHopeful - what is the problem with using the current version of Express, v4?  FYI, socket.io will also work with Express 3.  webSockets are really the way to solve this problem.  They are built specifically to allow servers to efficiently notify clients when something interesting has happened and that appears to be exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say version 3. The problem I am having with using Express is understanding how the routing works in conjunction with things like Socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

socket.io implementation is the solution for the current problem.
From expressjs application whenever there is a return of json object from an express router, you should emit the json object with specific event tag for client in the express method callback.

On client, you should listen to the above event and render the page variables accordingly.

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.